# Sort in postgres in ascending order with 0 last

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sql-order-by

So I'm trying to sort by the day of the week 0 - 6 (Sunday - Saturday), but I want Monday first. So in my database, I'm storing the day of the week with Sunday first which is 0. But can I sort it so Monday is first?

So it would be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0. Is this possible or should I store my data differently? Only storing it this way because that is how Date::DAYNAMES index the date of the week.

Right now I have something like:

```
TimeModel.order(:day_of_week)
```

Which is fine if I want Sunday first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in PostgreSQL to order for a specific value of the table :

```
TimeModel.order('CASE WHEN day_of_week = 0 THEN 7 ELSE day_of_week END')
```

This is a simple switch case statement in the PostgreSQL syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in Ruby, but the SQL query is easy: just sort on

```
(day_of_week + 6) % 7
```

where `%` is the modulus operation.

Comment: For me `(day_of_week - 1) % 7` would be more intuitive, but it doesn't work for me (Rails 4, postgres). I feel like this should work - am I missing something?